# Does Making a Controller in Laravel stops the php artisan serve to execute?

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-5

I was making a controller while the server default 
localhost:8000 for laravel was on.

After making the controller the server was not working and when i tried
command "php artisan serve" in terminal it gave me :-

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  parse error

What Should i do to make my project run again ?

Comment: Check `storage/logs/laravel.log` for details of the exception. Chances are your new controller has a parse error like a missing } or ; or something similar.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found out that it was due to a Syntax Error which can be found out by:

To search for syntax errors, go to your project directory and try linting the entire directory by running this command:

Command Here:-

### find -L ./ -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 php -l | grep     "Errors parsing".

If any syntax errors are present, the command will output the first file that has an error, the line where it occurs and the error message.

Comment: No need to do all that. You can just check the log.

Answer (score 1):

`artisan` commands will stop working when you've got this type of error somewhere in the app. Just find it (it seems there is one in a new controller), fix it and it will work.

Comment: Easiest way to find a parse error is to use IDE. Also, you can always look at Laravel error log. And read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to add to other answers, is to add `-v` to the `artisan` command you are using. This gives you a nice back trace, which helps finding possible bugs.

Like `php artisan -v serve`